# Does the Blue Dancer Charm work off weight percentage, or a hard value?

Tags: elden-ring

So, the [Blue Dancer's Charm](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Blue+Dancer+Charm) states that:

> The damage bonus has soft caps at 8(1.135x), 16(1.09x) and 20(1.0375x) equip weight. Once equip weight is 30 or higher the talisman has no effect.

This however states nothing about percentage, so I'm wondering if this works off your Endurance stat or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not, it only scales with the flat weight of your equipment. Your Endurance stats, how much you can carry and equipment load % do not increase or decrease the bonus of the amulet.